# Can the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem for zero placement in entire functions also be used for matrix-valued functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, soft-question, representation-theory

We know from complex analysis by the [Weierstrass Factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#The_elementary_factors) that we can design entire functions to be zero at specific points of interest.

This uses so called elementary factors:

$$E_n = \cases{1-z \hspace{5.5cm}\text{, if } n=0\\(1-z)\exp\left(\frac{z^1}{1} + \frac{z^2}2 +... +\frac{z^n}n \right)\hspace{0.5cm}\text{, otherwise}}$$
Where the expression inside the exponential function is a truncated Taylor expansion of a logarithmic function.

We can then go ahead to construct functions using these elementary factors which are zero at specified points. This gives us a kind of expansion or generalization for the fundamental theorem of algebra for complex numbers.

---

Now to my question, given that the exponential function also can be defined for matrices (for example by it's Taylor power series expansion). Would it also be possible for us to use the same or a similar technique to construct matrix-valued functions with specified zeroes ?

Why do I add representation theory? It is well known that one complex variable can be represented using $$z=a+bi { \text{ ("represented by") } } \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right]$$

I would like to consider functions $${\bf X} \to f({\bf X}), {\bf X} \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Maybe it would make more sense to consider ${\bf X} \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ given the nature of the question...?

Comment: Weierstrass sought to define *entire* functions given zeros, or to factor entire functions given their zeros. I love this question, but I am curious as to how you might define an "entire" matrix function, since linear maps are nice and continuous and differentiable by default (as far as I know!)

Comment: Yes I also don't know how to define "entire" for matrix functions. I suppose we will need to define some kind of smoothness or differentiability as well.

Comment: What kinds of functions do you mean: from matrices to matrices, from complex numbers to matrices, from matrices to complex numbers?

Comment: @Mindlack matrices to matrices. Maybe over the field of complex numbers would be more natural but my first idea was real numbers.